# Is it possible to change the column name while using CrudRepository method findById(Long Id)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I am using JPA, Spring boot for an sample application and extending CrudRepository. I making a REST call and passing an Id to search for all the rows with that Id.

Internally i am calling repository.findById(Long Id) method to do the search. However this method always does the search on "Primary key" column. Is it possible to use this method or any other method to make the search on the "Foreign Key" Column in same table?

My table has below columns

```
Name      DataType 
--------------------------------------
Id        BIGIN(8)      PK, AI
comment   VARCHAR(100)  Not Null
userId    BIGINT(8)     FK  Not Null
```

I want to search by userId but findById takes Id as default

Comment: Have you tried "findByUserId()" ? And maybe can you show us how you've mapped the entities ?

Comment: I dont get the option to use findByUserId().

Comment: Hey Ashish take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786968/writing-crudrepositorys-findby-method-on-a-field-annotated-by-joincolumn
You should be able to do something like `findByUserId(long userId)`

Comment: @AshishRanjan can you post your model classes please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add new method in the repository.

If you don't have any relation in entity class then use native query(assuming `Comment` as your entity)

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE userId = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Comment> findByUserId(long userId);
```

And if you have relation in entity class then use this.

```
List<Comment> findByUserId(long userId);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Having the @query annotation solved for me